# how can i access nested properties for CASL conditions

Tags: node.js, typescript, casl

I can't seem to access the nested object with the condition rule.
i want a user to have access to delete an article if the article's comment has the same id as the user.
these are just some made up classes to test...

here is my code:

```
import { defineAbility, AbilityBuilder } from '@casl/ability';

import { Ability, AbilityClass, ExtractSubjectType, InferSubjects } from '@casl/ability';

export class Article {
    static readonly modelName = "Article";
    static readonly __typename = "Article";
    constructor(  id: number,
        title: string,
        content: string,
        user: User,
        comment: Comment) {
            this.id = id
            this.title = title
            this.content = content
            this.user = user
            this.comment = comment
        }
  id: number
  title: string
  content: string
  user: User
  comment: Comment
}

export class User {
    static readonly modelName = "User"
    static readonly __typename = "User";
    constructor (id: number,
        name: string,
        comment: Comment) {
            this.id = id
            this.name = name
            this.comment = comment
        }
  id: number
  name: string
  comment: Comment
}

export class Comment {
    static readonly modelName = "Comment"
    static readonly __typename = "Comment";
  constructor(id: number,
    content: string,
    authorId: number) {
        this.id = id
        this.content = content
        this.authorId = authorId
    }
    id: number
  content: string
  authorId: number
}

type Action = 'create' | 'read' | 'update' | 'delete';
type Subjects = InferSubjects<typeof Article | typeof Comment| typeof User, true>;

export type AppAbility = Ability<[Action, Subjects]>;


export function createForUser(user: User) {
    const { can, cannot, build } = new AbilityBuilder<
      Ability<[Action, Subjects]>
    >(Ability as AbilityClass<AppAbility>);

    can('delete', Article, { comment: {id: user.comment.id}})

    return build({
      detectSubjectType: item => item.constructor as ExtractSubjectType<Subjects>
    });
  }
```

and im testing it with:

```
const comment = new Comment(0, 'a', 0)
const user = new User(1, 'sd', comment);
const article = new Article(2, 'sd', 'asd', user, comment)
const ability = createForUser(user);

console.log(ability.can('delete', article))// false
```

i saw somewhere that i need to do somthing like this:
`can('delete', Article, { 'comment.id': user.comment.id})`
but when i do is says 'Object literal may only specify known properties, and ''comment.id'' does not exist in type 'string[]'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ended up solving it like this:

```
export enum Action {
    Manage = 'manage',
    Create = 'create',
    Read   = 'read',
    Update = 'update',
    Delete = 'delete',
}

export type Subject = InferSubjects<typeof Article | 
                                     typeof Comment | 
                                     typeof User | 
                                     'all';

export type AppAbility = PureAbility<[Action, Subject]>;
export const AppAbility = Ability as AbilityClass<AppAbility>;
```

and then defining rules like this:

```
createForUser(user: User) {
  const { can, cannot, build } = new AbilityBuilder(AppAbility);
  
  
  can(Action.Read, Article, { 'comment.id': 1 });

    
  return build({
    detectSubjectType: item => item.constructor as ExtractSubjectType<Subject>
  });
}
```

Comment: It’s unclear for me  how you got type safety in defining `comment.id`  Could you please show the classes you use for subjects?

Comment: The classes I used are the same as the ones in the question. I don't get warnings/any validation when using this syntax.. but its the only thing I got to work.

Comment: By using `PureAbility`, which is the main difference I can spot, I'm also loosing all type safety when defining my abilities...

Answer (score 7):

You can find  “Nested fields with dot notation” section on https://casl.js.org/v5/en/advanced/typescript useful. In short, when you use for notation to define conditions together with typescript, you need to create a custom type:

```
type FlatArticle = Article & {
  'comment.id': Article['comment']['id']
};

can<FlatArticle>('read', Article, { 'comment.id': 1 });
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, i know this is a way to do it but i don't "want" to define each property again. ended up finding a solution.

Comment: There is no other way to achieve this in typescript. At least until ts 4.1 with string literal types. Property paths were always an issue in ts

Comment: Casl does it somehow.. look at the answer I posted, casl 
manages to flatten it.

Comment: You was a perfect! It solved my problem, your answer deserves a prize!

Comment: a million thanks